# What data structure in Scala is Python's nested dictionary or a csv?

Tags: python, scala, csv, dictionary, apache-spark

I am using Scala in a Spark shell. I have data reduced down to an RDD, `byHour: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[47] at reduceByKey at <console>:16` or if collected an array, `byHour: Array[(String, Int)]`, that looks like:

```
Array((6497+2006-03-19 20:00,13), (7511+2006-03-17 02:00,1), (13508+2006-03-26 10:00,4), (217+2006-05-16 16:00,1), (12404+2006-03-27 15:00,1), (9777+2006-05-14 09:00,1), (10291+2006-03-03 17:00,2), (4781+2006-05-10 14:00,2), (10291+2006-04-26 17:00,1), (15198+2006-04-26 12:00,1))
```

I would like to store this similar to a nested dictionary in Python or a csv file.

In Python I would create

```
{"6497": {"2006-03-19 20:00": 13, "2006-03-19 22:00": 1}, "7511": {"2006-03-17 02:00": 1}...}
```

In the end I want

```
userid, 2006-03-17 01:00, 2006-03-17 02:00, ... , 2006-03-19 20:00, 2006-03-19 21:00, 2006-03-19 22:00
6497,0,0, ..., 13,0,1
7511,0,1, ..., 0,0,0
```

I am not sure how to get there in Scala. I think I need a list or set of hash maps or a hashMap[String => hashMap].

---

Update:
byHour is an RDD[(String, Int)]

```
val byUserHour = byHour.map(x => (x._1.split("\\+")(0),(x._1.split("\\+")(1),x._2)))
val byUser = byUserHour.groupByKey
val times = byHour.map(x => x._1.split("\\+")(1)).distinct.collect.sortWith(_ < _)
val broadcastTimes = sc.broadcast(times)
val userMaps = byUser.mapValues { 
  x => x.map{
    case(time,cnt) => time -> cnt
  }.toMap
}
val result = userMaps.map {
  case(u,ut) => (u +: broadcastTimes.value.map(ut.getOrElse(_,0).toString))}
val lines = result.map(_.mkString(","))
val header = List("userid") ::: times.toList
```

Comment: given you're using Spark, do you need a distributed approach or are you rather exploring on a single node?  The answer will depend on that.

Comment: A distributed approach would be preferred.

Comment: will you have a known fix amount of rows in your model? (csv-like?) or would that depend on the data?

Comment: I do know how many userids I have, but sometimes I won't.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask for columns. As you are asking for data structures, a case class might help but it could become unwieldy for too many elements (time columns in your case)

Comment: I could scan through the data to find all of the column names, but there are going to be a lot of them (every hour for a couple months).

Comment: Case classes won't help in that case. The edited answer of Daniel is good advice. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would split off the user ID, so you get a `data: Seq[(String, String, Int)]`. Then, group by user ID:

```
val byUser: Map[String, Seq[(String, String, Int)]] = data.groupBy(_._1)
```

Now we can create a map per user:

```
val userMaps: Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = byUser.mapValues {
  s => s.map {
    case (user, time, n) => time -> n
  }.toMap
}
```

For the final formatting you first need to get the distinct timestamps, then look those up in the per-user maps:

```
val times: Seq[String] = data.map(_._2).toSet.toList
val result: Seq[Seq[String]] = userMaps.toSeq.map {
  case (u, ut) => (u +: times.map(ut.getOrElse(_, 0).toString))
}
val lines: Seq[String] = result.map(_.mkString(","))
```

Hope this is enough to get you started. You can read more about Scala collections at http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html (and lots of other places).

---

All the above would be a local computation — not distributed at all. To do the same in a distributed way, you would read your data into an RDD at the start (`sc.textFile()`), and perform roughly the same sequence of operations.

A minor difference is that instead of `groupBy` you have `groupByKey`, which behaves a bit differently. From `RDD[A, B]` you get `RDD[A, Iterable[B]]`, not `Map[A, Seq[(A, B)]]`.

A major difference is that you need to collect `times` from the cluster to the application, and then broadcast it to all nodes:

```
val times: Seq[String] = data.map(_._2).distinct.collect
val broadcast = sc.broadcast(times)
val result: RDD[Seq[String]] = userMaps.map {
  val times = broadcast.value
  case (u, ut) => (u +: times.map(ut.getOrElse(_, 0).toString))
}
```

Comment: I don't know how distributed this is, but it works. Thank you

Comment: You are right, it is not at all distributed. (I should have noted that.) I have now added an overview of how it would be done in a distributed way. I hope it makes sense... If you have more questions, check out http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html! (Or ask here.)

Comment: Thanks for the overview on the distributed. I was able to get to my answer. However, I am not sure if mine is as distributed as it could be given it works on small datasets, but never returns on the larger dataset (2G).

Comment: Yeah, that happens :). There could be several reasons. With this algorithm a risk is that the number of distinct timestamps may be too large, and each row in the output becomes huge. Good luck with debugging!